# Finding the starting angular momenta of a coupled angular momenta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

I'm having problem with an exercise:

> We consider the total angular moment J of a spin-1 and a spin-1/2
>   particles.
>
> $J := L^{(1)} + L^{(2)}$
>
> where
>
> $L^{(1)}_i:= L_i ⊗ 1$ and $L^{(2)}_i:= 1 ⊗ L_i, i = x, y, z$
>
> Construct a representation of all the eigenstates $|3/2, m_J>$ and  $|1/2, m_J>$ of $J$ and $J_z$ regarding the eigenstates of $(L^{(k)})^2$ and $L_z$.

I know that $m^{(1)} + m^{(2)} = m_J$, but I have no clue on how to find the $l^{(1)}$ and $l^{(2)}$.

And applying the equivalences between eigenvalues and eigenstates of both $L^{(i)}$ and $L_z$ doesn't seem to bring me anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, $l^{(1)}$ and $l^{(2)}$ are fixed because they correspond to the spin of the particles ($l^{(1)} = 1$ and $l{(2)} = 1/2$). Because there are $3\times2 =6$ possible states in the tensor product, the usual way of constructing representations is finding the highest $J^z$ and then lowering the state with $J^{-} = (J^x-iJ^y)$. Thus, you would have maximum $J^z = 3/2$ and thus a $J=3/2$ representation with 4 states, plus 2 more states yielding a representation of $J= 1/2$.

They ask you to write the 4 states (with $m_J = 3/2,1/2,-1/2,-3/2$) for the $J=3/2$ representation in terms of the ones you started with. It is clear that 
$$\left|3/2,3/2\right> = \left|1,1\right>\otimes \left|1/2,1/2\right> $$
Now you should lower this state applying $J^-$ (with the correct normalisation). You can as well look at a [table of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#_j1=1,_j2=1/2). Either way
$$\left|3/2,1/2\right> = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\left(\left|1,0\right>\otimes \left|1/2,1/2\right> \right) + \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}}\left(\left|1,1\right>\otimes \left|1/2,-1/2\right> \right)$$
and now act with $J^-$ again to obtain
$$\left|3/2,-1/2\right> = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}}\left(\left|1,-1\right>\otimes \left|1/2,1/2\right> \right) + \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\left(\left|1,0\right>\otimes \left|1/2,-1/2\right> \right)$$
and finally check that applying $J^-$ again you get
$$\left|3/2,-3/2\right> = \left|1,-1\right>\otimes \left|1/2,-1/2\right> $$

This is the usual way to construct tensor product representations of $SU(2)$, you assume they will be a sum of highest weight representations (I think this is proven for finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebras, but I am not completely sure).

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful, but the thing I'm missing (maybe it's a bit of a dumb question) is how is it clear that: 

$\left|3/2,3/2\right> = \left|1,1\right>\otimes \left|1/2,1/2\right>$ ?

Comment: Because it is the only way you can obtain $m_z = 3/2$, just having both $z$ components to be $+1$ and $+1/2$ (remember $J^z = L_z^{(1)} + L_z^{(2)}$)

Comment: So $\left|1/2,1/2\right> = \left|0,0\right>\otimes \left|1/2,1/2\right>$, right?

Comment: Yes, the spin 0 particle does not affect the total spin of the state (then you would have to consider orbital angular momentum as well)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the point I was missing! I didn't know how to start...